# How to get BitBucket to Work on Windows XP Operating System?

Tags: windows-xp, bitbucket, tortoisegit

How do I get Bitbucket to work on Windows XP Operating System??

I can't download SourceTree because SourceTree doesn't support Windows XP.
I downloaded TortoiseGit but when I tried to run it, it says that I need to download Windows Service Pack. I have the latest version- Windows Service Pack 3 so when I try to update, there is nothing to update.

Thanks

Comment: you can use command line tools

Comment: When you use a 13 year old operating system it is best to stick with 13 year old tools.  Not a lucky number, time to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use GitEye http://www.collab.net/giteyeapp is an a Free git client multi-platform and works in XP

Comment: I downloaded this into windows xp, ran and installed giteye (a walloping 100mb), and when I tried to clone repository, bitbucket isn't even on the list as a provider to choose from!! Yes, it works on windows xp.. but it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

I have just managed to get BitBucket work on Windows XP.
You should install Git for Windows (https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.7.0.windows.1/Git-2.7.0-32-bit.exe)
Make sure Git Gui is installed.
After that, just open Git Gui and clone repository (local to BitBucket or vise versa).
Location of the remote repository on BitBucket should be the link shown in the overview page on the BitBucket site. You can choose HTTPS or SSH link of your BitBucket repository.

Comment: Latest supported version of git-for-windows is 2.10.0, https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.10.0.windows.1